# quip - spreadsheet with records

Tags: quip

I'm the sole SF admin in my company and I'm thinking about implementing quip.

I would like to know if this feature could be possible doing with quip:
I want to have the ability to create a spreadsheet with raw data and to have a column that would be a formula based on other columns (so far like a google spreadsheet or microsoft excel) but also to "connect" each row to a SF record and in that way to update a field in each record with the formula in the column.

So I want to have both abilities in the same feature: to create manipulations on raw data but to connect them to SF records.